# Why does the accuracy drop while the loss decrease, as the number of epochs increases?

Tags: neural-networks, overfitting, loss, accuracy, epochs

I've been trying to find the optimal number of epochs that I should train my neural network (that I just implemented) for.

The visualizations below show the neural network being run with a variable number of epochs. It is quite obvious that the accuracy increases with the number of epochs. However, at 75 epochs, we see a dip before the accuracy continues to rise. What is the cause of this?

[image]

Comment: You really need to provide more details about your problem, neural network and data. Is your model a simple multi-layer perceptron (i.e. not recurrent connections or convolutions)? How many layers does it have (and how many neurons per layer)? If you are using the MSE loss, I suppose that you are using a regression problem, but you're using the accuracy... So, which problem exactly? How many data points do you have? Please, edit your post to include all these details.

Answer (score 1):

Decrease of loss does not essentially lead to increase of accuracy (most of the time it happens but sometime it may not happen). To know why, you can have a look at [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/282160/how-is-it-possible-that-validation-loss-is-increasing-while-validation-accuracy) question. The network cares about decreasing the loss and it does not care about the accuracy at all. So it's no surprise to see what you presented.

*Additional note*: If you use **batch** approaches to teach your network, *or* if you choose a **big step size** you may also see that the loss increases sometimes but in the case of batching, the hope is that its trend is to be decreased.